# php parse data from strange xml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Hi all could somebody help me to parse data from following xml ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"       xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
    <Cube time='2014-10-23'>
        <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.2669'/>
        <Cube currency='JPY' rate='136.42'/>
        <Cube currency='BGN' rate='1.9558'/>
        <Cube currency='CZK' rate='27.690'/>
        <Cube currency='DKK' rate='7.4462'/>
        <Cube currency='GBP' rate='0.79040'/>
        <Cube currency='HUF' rate='307.40'/>
        <Cube currency='LTL' rate='3.4528'/>
        <Cube currency='PLN' rate='4.2290'/>
        <Cube currency='RON' rate='4.4245'/>
        <Cube currency='SEK' rate='9.1869'/>
        <Cube currency='CHF' rate='1.2067'/>
        <Cube currency='NOK' rate='8.3090'/>
        <Cube currency='HRK' rate='7.6733'/>
        <Cube currency='RUB' rate='52.6736'/>
        <Cube currency='TRY' rate='2.8336'/>
        <Cube currency='AUD' rate='1.4404'/>
        <Cube currency='BRL' rate='3.1596'/>
        <Cube currency='CAD' rate='1.4208'/>
        <Cube currency='CNY' rate='7.7542'/>
        <Cube currency='HKD' rate='9.8279'/>
        <Cube currency='IDR' rate='15257.82'/>
        <Cube currency='ILS' rate='4.7737'/>
        <Cube currency='INR' rate='77.5153'/>
        <Cube currency='KRW' rate='1339.01'/>
        <Cube currency='MXN' rate='17.1095'/>
        <Cube currency='MYR' rate='4.1440'/>
        <Cube currency='NZD' rate='1.6115'/>
        <Cube currency='PHP' rate='56.775'/>
        <Cube currency='SGD' rate='1.6134'/>
        <Cube currency='THB' rate='40.993'/>
        <Cube currency='ZAR' rate='13.8557'/>
    </Cube>
</Cube>
```

I am trying do get currency='CZK' and its rate with following code

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 $cv = curl_version();
  $user_agent = "curl ${cv['version']} (${cv['host']}) libcurl/${cv['version']}         ${cv['ssl_version']} zlib/${cv['libz_version']} <" . EMAIL_ADDRESS . ">"; 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "deflate, gzip, identity");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
 $xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 echo $xml_data;
    $parser = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
echo $parser;
```

the only result for $xml_data  is "Reference rates European Central Bank"
and for $parser nothing

Why result for $xml_data is only "Reference rates European Central Bank" and not rest of xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ian had already pointed out, the $parser is an object and so you will not be able to simply echo it.

If you are only after the value for 'CZK' then you can use the following code:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 $cv = curl_version();
 $user_agent = "curl ${cv['version']} (${cv['host']}) libcurl/${cv['version']}         ${cv['ssl_version']} zlib/${cv['libz_version']} <" . EMAIL_ADDRESS . ">"; 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "deflate, gzip, identity");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
 $xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 $parser = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);

 // Echo the rate for CZK
 echo $parser->Cube->Cube->Cube[3]['rate'];

 // Echo the currency 
 echo $parser->Cube->Cube->Cube[3]['currency'];
```

Obviously the above code snippet relies on the XML feed returning the data in the same order every time. You should look in to selecting the correct node based on the attribute in order to target the correct element each time instead.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) `simplexml_load_string` interprets an XML string into an object. Echo won't display the full object, so you'll want to use print_r($parser) to view all the data from the XML file on your page (though using a debugger like xdebug is much more efficient and will allow you to view the data in your variables without echoing them to the page).

You'll see that each of the cubes are represented as objects and then their attributes are arrays. You should be able to easily to loop through and get the data you need.

You can get the full object tree below with `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $parser, true ) . '</pre>';`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Cube] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Cube] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [time] => 2014-10-23
                        )

                    [Cube] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => USD
                                            [rate] => 1.2669
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => JPY
                                            [rate] => 136.42
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => BGN
                                            [rate] => 1.9558
                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => CZK
                                            [rate] => 27.690
                                        )

                                )

                            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => DKK
                                            [rate] => 7.4462
                                        )

                                )

                            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => GBP
                                            [rate] => 0.79040
                                        )

                                )

                            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => HUF
                                            [rate] => 307.40
                                        )

                                )

                            [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => LTL
                                            [rate] => 3.4528
                                        )

                                )

                            [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => PLN
                                            [rate] => 4.2290
                                        )

                                )

                            [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => RON
                                            [rate] => 4.4245
                                        )

                                )

                            [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => SEK
                                            [rate] => 9.1869
                                        )

                                )

                            [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => CHF
                                            [rate] => 1.2067
                                        )

                                )

                            [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => NOK
                                            [rate] => 8.3090
                                        )

                                )

                            [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => HRK
                                            [rate] => 7.6733
                                        )

                                )

                            [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => RUB
                                            [rate] => 52.6736
                                        )

                                )

                            [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => TRY
                                            [rate] => 2.8336
                                        )

                                )

                            [16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => AUD
                                            [rate] => 1.4404
                                        )

                                )

                            [17] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => BRL
                                            [rate] => 3.1596
                                        )

                                )

                            [18] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => CAD
                                            [rate] => 1.4208
                                        )

                                )

                            [19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => CNY
                                            [rate] => 7.7542
                                        )

                                )

                            [20] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => HKD
                                            [rate] => 9.8279
                                        )

                                )

                            [21] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => IDR
                                            [rate] => 15257.82
                                        )

                                )

                            [22] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => ILS
                                            [rate] => 4.7737
                                        )

                                )

                            [23] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => INR
                                            [rate] => 77.5153
                                        )

                                )

                            [24] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => KRW
                                            [rate] => 1339.01
                                        )

                                )

                            [25] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => MXN
                                            [rate] => 17.1095
                                        )

                                )

                            [26] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => MYR
                                            [rate] => 4.1440
                                        )

                                )

                            [27] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => NZD
                                            [rate] => 1.6115
                                        )

                                )

                            [28] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => PHP
                                            [rate] => 56.775
                                        )

                                )

                            [29] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => SGD
                                            [rate] => 1.6134
                                        )

                                )

                            [30] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => THB
                                            [rate] => 40.993
                                        )

                                )

                            [31] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => ZAR
                                            [rate] => 13.8557
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually use this bank's xml. I am very happy it gives historical 90-day xml as well. I approached this differently. I created an array with all the currencies as keys and made them equal to the rate. Then I can just use my array to get rate as follows:

```
$xml=file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

// base rate EUR    
$_RATES['EUR']=1;

foreach($xml as $line){
  if(preg_match("/currency='([[:alpha:]]+)'/",$line,$currency)){
    if(preg_match("/rate='([[:graph:]]+)'/", $line,$rate)){$_RATES[$currency[1]]=$rate[1];}
  }
}
```

Now your rate is in `$_RATES["CZK"]`

This easily allows you to easily exchange it into any currency. For example, if you want the rate from USD to CZK and get the exchanged value you just do:

```
$converted = ($_RATES[$currency_to]/$_RATES[$currency_from]) * $value;
```

Hope this helps someone.